# Small codes with transversal Hadamard

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

The fewer qubits it uses the better. Also, it would be great if the code admitted a transversal logical $CNOT$.

Answer (score 3):

Every [CSS code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_code) has transversal CNOT gate. Moreover, if the $X$ and $Z$ sectors of the stabilizer are isomorphic then the code has transversal Hadamard. See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15305/10480) for proofs of both facts. The CSS construction is also described in section 10.4.2 on page 450 in Nielsen & Chuang.

This leads us to the smallest non-trivial code with transversal CNOT and Hadamard. Namely, the $[\![4,2,2]\!]$ code with stabilizer group generated by $XXXX$ and $ZZZZ$. See [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27520/10480) for arguments that rule out smaller codes.

Comment: I believe that CSS codes are also the *only* codes with transversal CNOT

Comment: May you expand with the corresponding logical Hadamard?

Comment: @unknown It's not hard to show that CSS codes are the only *stabilizer* codes with transversal CNOT. Is it true that non-additive codes cannot have transversal CNOT?

Comment: @DanieleCuomo You can apply simultaneous logical Hadamard to both encoded qubits using $HHHH$. However, note that $|00_L\rangle$ has entanglement across every partitioning of the physical qubits while $|{0+}_L\rangle$ lacks entanglement across some partitions, so Hadamard on just one of the two encoded qubits is not transversal. If this is a problem you can ignore the second logical qubit and pretend you only have one. Then $HHHH$ is transversal Hadamard on your only logical qubit. N.B. such ignored qubits can be utilized to reduce weights of measured operators, see subsystem codes.

Comment: @AdamZalcman can I state, as immediate inference from your answer, that: there is no code admitting logical hadamard and at the same time able to detect only X (xor Z) noise? As for the case of the repetition code.